# How to handle the "relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against protected symbol" when writing shared objects in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, elf, gnu-assembler, binutils

I am writing an object file in assembly language to be included in a shared object.  I am using the GNU toolchain, and my target is `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`.  Please consider the following (example) source:

```
        .text
        .globl  f
f:      leaq    g(%rip),%rax
        ret
        .data
        .globl  g
        .protected g
g:      .quad   8
```

The crucial parts are the global protected symbol `g` and the reference to `g` in `f`.  When I assemble the source using `gcc -c -o example.o --shared -fpic example.s`, `objdump -x` tells me that `gas` inserted a relocation for the local reference (some relocation entry is obviously necessary):

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE
0000000000000003 R_X86_64_PC32     g-0x0000000000000004
```

The problem shows up when I try also to link the file:

```
$ gcc -o example.so --shared -fpic example.s
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccQ6BcLl.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against protected symbol `g' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As far as I think I have understood by reading [Ian Lance Taylor's blog](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/307) (but I might be mistaken), this is due to the fact that the linker cannot guarantee pointer equality when symbol interposition happens (in some other object file).

As this will never be an actual problem with my symbol `g` in my shared object, I would like to silence `ld`.  The [Linux ABI 0.1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/linux-abi/linux-abi-draft.pdf) seems to say that I should add a `.note.gnu.property` section to my source that contains a setting of `GNU_PROPERTY_NO_COPY_ON_PROTECTED`.  How can I do this in practice?

If possible, I don't want to add extra flags to the invocation of the assembler and linker, so I am looking for a solution where the necessary modifications are just part of the source file.

Comment: One possible work-around is to define a second label at the same address, but without `.global`.  (Or across files within a shared library, `.hidden` so it's visible within this shared object but not from outside, so it doesn't participate in symbol-interposition or dynamic linking at all.)  But that's more clunky, and the docs for `.protected` (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Protected.html) sound like that's what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reference the symbol like this because while it is now protected from interposition, it is still subject to the same behaviour any object-type symbol exported from a shared library is.  To fix this, go through the GOT like with any other exported object-type symbol.

## Background

The designers of the ELF ABI intended shared objects to be transparent to the main program.  ELF ABI programs (but not shared objects) are wholy ignorant to the presence of shared objects and are written as if all symbols used by the program were statically linked into the program.  This includes object-type symbols, to which direct access is permitted.  E.g. the main program can do

```
movq    g(%rip), %rax
```

and gets the value of the same variable `g` your shared library uses.  The way this works is that for all object-type symbols referenced by your main program but provided by a shared library, the linker looks up the size of the symbol at link time and allocates that much space in the BSS segment of the executable.  The symbol (`g` in this case) is resolved to point to that space.

At load time, the dynamic loader finds the shared library that defines `g` and copies the data for `g` from the data segment of the shared object into the space reserved in the BSS segment of the main executable and resolves the GOT entry for `g` to that address.  This is called a [copy relocation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-0641/6j9vuqujb/index.html#chapter4-84604).  Thus, the shared library, when accessing `g` will access the same variable the main program can access. (If the main program does not access `g`, copy relocation does not take place and `g` is resolved to its definition within the shared library's data/BSS segment)

However, this scheme only works if the shared library accesses the symbol through the GOT as the symbol is not relocated with the shared library.  Thus, you must go through the GOT to access the symbol.

I.e. do

```
        movq g@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax  # find the address of g
        movq (%rax), %rax            # load the value of g
```

The address of `g` will not change while the program is running, so it suffices to do this once at the beginning of your code.  The overhead should be low.

## Workarounds

Workarounds include:

- consider making the symbol hidden and only exposing it to the main executable through an accessor function, returning its address.  You can use map files (version scripts) to set the visibility for all functions in your library in one spot, which may be easier than annotating the symbols in the source files.
- if it doesn't matter if the main executable and your library see the same address for the symbol (e.g. if it's a constant), you can provide a hidden alias for the symbol and use that for internal references
- you can use `-Bsymbolic` to have the shared library always use its own copy of the symbol, even if it is subject to copy relocation.  Be aware that this effectively disables the ability to share variables between shared library and main executable.  You'll also not be able to compare function pointers for equality correctly.  This option should not be used in production for this reason.
- If you cannot use an accessor function for some reason, you could detour the exported symbol through a pointer, only allowing copy-relocations on the pointer:

  ```
          .bss
          .globl local_g
          .hidden local_g
  local_g:
          .space 8
          .data
          .globl g
  g:      .quad local_g
  ```

  In the main binary, declare `g` as holding a pointer to the variable and dereference it to access the variable.  Consider declariing it `const` so it cannot be dereferenced by accident.  Note that this approach performs worse than going through the GOT for accesses from other shared objects to the symbol.
- You can use `-mno-direct-extern-access` during compilation of all program parts and linking (shared library and main executable) to avoid copy relocations (you might also need to link all parts with `-Wz,nocopyreloc`.  Note that shared libraries compiled such are ABI-incompatible to main programs that were compiled without this option and must not be linked to them.  The other way round is ok.

The best option however is to just go through the GOT as with any other global symbol.

Comment: So the GAS manual is wrong when is says "*This directive overrides the named symbols default visibility (which is set by their binding: local, global or weak). The directive sets the visibility to protected which means that **any references to the symbols from within the components that defines them must be resolved to the definition in that component**, even if a definition in another component would normally preempt this.*"?  (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Protected.html). Or is that still true if you go through the GOT, so it's a missed-opt in the toolchain to disallow it?

Comment: Or for a shared object, "the component that defines them" might still not be this component, it might be the main executable?  (I thought that was just a special case of interposition, so I found your answer surprising; I think it would be good to be specific about what `.protected` does rule out.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The statement is not wrong.  The definition is still the same; if the main program was to define it's own `g` symbol, it would get a separate variable.  But if it merely *references* `g`, it'll get the `g` defined by the shared library.  For that to work, the possibility of copy relocations must be preserved.  Copy relocations are orthogonal to symbol interposition.

Comment: I.e. copy relocations make it so that the actual location of the symbol can be in the main binary to satisfy the ABI requirements; this'll still be the same symbol the shared library has defined, it's just not relocated the same way as the rest of the library and thus cannot be accessed through R_X86_64_PC32.

Comment: In my application, the symbol points at mutable data (the data is mutated by the shared object code).  If I understand you correctly, the hidden alias technique (suggested by @PeterCordes would not work then.  What is "GNU_PROPERTY_NO_COPY_ON_PROTECTED" supposed to do if it does not prevent copying of the symbol's data?

Comment: The dynamic linker can, in principle, patch the text segment of the main program so that its reference to `g` points to wherever the shared library's data segment was loaded, can't it?

Comment: @Marc If you set this property, then I believe linking with an executable that references the symbol in a way that would require copy relocations will just fail.  I recommend you just go through the GOT to grab the symbol.  Is there any reason why you don't want to do this?

Comment: @Marc ELF is specifically designed such that text is immutable and no runtime relocations happen there.  AFAIK it can be done with special options, but then you're asking any user of your library to link with these options.

Comment: I see, thanks for the reminder on how things worked.  Is there a way to require the main executable to go through the GOT while letting the shared library access "directly"?  I guess your suggestion of doing it manually by calling an accessor function to return the address (of a `.hidden` variable) would have pretty similar asm, except without alias-analysis benefits of static storage being known to not overlap with other globals.

Comment: @PeterCordes You could leave the symbol hidden and build a DIY GOT to access it.  I'll add an example for that.  This'll make access from other shared libraries slower though, as they'll now have to go through two GOTs to get the symbol.

Comment: @fuz: Last I checked, 64-bit absolute addresses worked in PIE executables, with merely a warning about `DT_TEXTREL`.  Yeah, I checked with `global main` / `main: mov rdx, main` / `ret` in NASM.  And link with `gcc foo.o`.  I got linker warnings: `warning: relocation in read-only section '.text'` / `warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE`. Same with `gcc -shared foo.o` to make a `.so`.  So it is supported in practice on GNU / Linux, even though it goes against the design intent of ELF.

Comment: @Marc: Yes, the linker can patch the main executable, but only if it used 64-bit addressing, not efficient RIP-relative.  Shared libraries typically get loaded more than +- 2GiB away from the main executable so 32-bit relative addressing can't reach.  ([32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)).  Perhaps some combination of `-mcmodel=medium` and an attribute like `__attribute__((section(".largedata")))` (that's probably the wrong name) in the `.h` or something could get the compiler to use 64-bit absolute for only this one variable?

Comment: But probably GCC doesn't support that; the only option I see is `-mlarge-data-threshold=THRESHOLD` to decide based on size, the manual doesn't mention an attribute.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added a bit about a new gcc option that could help.  It breaks the ABI though.  I'm not sure if text relocations will avoid the need for copy relocations.  These should be orthogonal, too.

Comment: @fuz I thought that applying relocations to the main executable would be no problem because they would happen before the program starts (and the text could be made read-only in time).  Anyway, the reason why I asked was that I thought the extra indirection through the GOT would not be needed (thanks to `protected`) and that I could have used the same code generator (the assembly is not generated by hand) for a shared object and the main executable.  I have learnt a lot this evening.  Thanks!

Comment: @Marc Always happy to help!  Note that if you want to use the same code generation for both, you can just unconditionally go through the GOT to fetch the symbol.  This works in the main binary too, even if it is statically linked.

Comment: Text relocations could hypothetically avoid the need for copy relocations by letting the main executable (and other libs?) directly access .data / .bss of the shared object that defines the var.  (Like `-mno-direct-extern-access` but with neither going through the GOT.  I agree that it might be more efficient to just have one or the other use the GOT, and it's cool that `-mno-direct-extern-access` lets you choose which, so e.g. you can give the shared lib direct access if it uses its own globals a lot more than the main executable does.  But that option affects *all* globals, not per-variable)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, but the linker is still going to use copy relocations unless you explicitly disable them (`-z nocopyreloc`).

Comment: @fuz I have a simple follow-up question: Assume that I have a bunch of consecutive global variables in my shared object source, which will be copy relocated. Can I define a hidden symbol through which I can access the start and the end of the area (after copy relocation)?

Comment: @Marc: A `.hidden` symbol in the shared library *won't* be copy-relocated, so you'd be accessing the unused storage space in the library's .bss or .data.  Did you mean a global symbol name that's otherwise unused, but has the same address as the first real variable? Like `foo:` `bar: .long 123`?  I'm not sure the order (and contiguousness) is guaranteed for the copy-relocation copies in the main executable's .bss or .data; that would be something to check on.

Comment: Yes, I mean a symbol representing an absolute address. One for the start, one for the end.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I can answer this question myself.  I don't see how the contiguousness can be guaranteed because the main executable may not reference all such symbols of the shared object, so there will only be space in the .bss for a subset of the symbols to be copy-relocated.